# Can't get the value form an input with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this field

```
<input type="number">
```

and this JS code:

```
$(':input[type="number"]').on('propertychange change click keyup input paste', function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 188) {
        console.log($(this).val());
    }
});
```

Why the `console.log()` don't return me the value into my field ?

Thanks.

Comment: ditch the `:`; it's not a pseudo element you're selecting, just an element

Comment: remove "`:`" ... .

Comment: @giorgio : doesn't work.

Comment: See here: https://jsfiddle.net/9m5fcaom/

Answer (score 0):

As input is type `number` this display as a number : you have to write a correct number to being displayed : try to type `1` and `,` displaying '1'